# How to use cvBlob for detecting connected component?

Tags: c, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I want to get the connected component from an image with each components boundary pixels information,How can I use cvBlob library for the same..!!!

Though I have used cvFindContours forthis But I am not getting the desired result.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you specify what is the problem with using cvFindContours?

Comment: Actually I am not understanding the output of cvFindContours,Hence I am unable to use that output.I want to get the boundary pixels of all the connected component,and smooth this contour.

Comment: cvFindContour is a cvSeq structure. You can access every pixel of a  contour and draw it to another picture. Can you please give link to the picture?

Answer (score 0):

[This may help someone having similar problem]

If you provided a picture, you would have got the guidance on your problem. It's extremely hard to imagine what kind of picture you got.

The function findContours() may be finding all contours in your image, including those you do not need. You can always filter out certain contours as being too small, or too large. :)